# How to hist() plot each data array row of a 2d NumPy array with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3x10 2d ndarray that I would like to do a matplotlib hist plot. I want a hist plot of each array row in one subplot. I tried supplying the ndarray directly but discovered matplotlib would provide hist plots of each column of the ndarray, which is not what I want. How can I achieve my objective?  Presently, I have to explicitly declare the `hist()` commands for each row and I would prefer to avoid this approach.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.array([[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1,   2,  4, 5],
              [4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 6, 6,  7,   6,  5, 7],
              [5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10]] )

print( '\nd', d )
             
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 1)
dcount, dbins, dignored = ax[0].hist( d, bins=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], histtype='bar', label='d' )
d0count, d0bins, d0ignored = ax[1].hist( d[0,:], bins=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], histtype='bar', label='d0', alpha=0.2 )
d1count, d1bins, d1ignored = ax[2].hist( d[1,:], bins=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], histtype='bar', label='d1', alpha=0.2 )
d2count, d2bins, d2ignored = ax[3].hist( d[2,:], bins=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], histtype='bar', label='d2', alpha=0.2 )
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
ax[2].legend()
ax[3].legend()
print( '\ndcount', dcount )
print( '\ndbins', dbins )
print( '\ndignored', dignored )
print( '\nd0count', d0count )
print( '\nd0bins', d0bins )
print( '\nd0ignored', d0ignored )
print( '\nd1count', d0count )
print( '\nd1bins', d0bins )
print( '\nd1ignored', d0ignored )
print( '\nd2count', d0count )
print( '\nd2bins', d0bins )
print( '\nd2ignored', d0ignored )
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpler way. Transpose `d`. That is, replace

```
dcount, dbins, dignored = ax[0].hist( d, bins=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], histtype='bar', label='d' )
```

with

```
dcount, dbins, dignored = ax[0].hist( d.T, bins=[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], histtype='bar', label=['d0', 'd1','d2'], alpha=0.5 )
```

[image: fig1a]

I was hoping for matplotlib's `hist()` command would have some command to do it but did not find it. Transposing the numpy array worked. I wonder if this is the usual way matplotlib user to do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
# import needed packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

---

### Create data to plot

Using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520) and [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html):

```
gaussian0=[np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1.5) for _ in range(100)]
gaussian1=[np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=0.5) for _ in range(100)]

gaussians = [gaussian0, gaussian1]
```

---

### Plot with one hist call only

```
for gaussian in gaussians:
    plt.hist(gaussian,alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I think there should be a simpler way to plot a 2d numpy array than to use a for-loop.